# How to complete my JavaScript coding homework

Tags: javascript

I am stuck on [this assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0Qgk.png) and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I did this which in my head should pass the question but according to the custom website we have to do it on the answer is wrong and I don't know what else to do.

```
//writes the parameters 1-10                                        
var result = "";                                        
                                        
function count(num1, num2)                                      
{                                       
  for (var i = num1 + 1; i <= num2; i++)                                        
  {                                     
    result += i;                                        
                                        
    if (i < num2)                                       
    {                                       
      result += ",";                                        
    }                                       
  }                                     
  return result;                                        
                                        
}
```

I attempted this with the help of my friends and with chatgpt to assist me in what I could be doing wrong, however it doesn't really give the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Have you tried actually running your code and see what it returns for the given examples? [It doesn't in fact return what it should be returning](https://jsfiddle.net/js4v61rk/).

Comment: Your `var result` should be **inside** the function, not outside.

Comment: try to use `let result = ""` _inside_ the function definition and also, the problem states, that it should start with the first given number, so `let i = num1` and not `let i = num1 + 1`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From what I understood, the only thing that seems to be missing is the starting number:

```js
function count(num1, num2)                                      
{        
  let result = ""; // Always initialise in function to ensure it always sends the current result only.                                       
  for (let i = num1; i <= num2; i++) // Set i = num1 instead of num+1
  {        
    result += i;
    if (i < num2) { result += ","; }                      
  }
  return result;                                     
}
```

Comment: The `let i = num1;` statement is unnecessary

Comment: Agreed, updated the answer : )

Answer (score 0):

This is not an *actual* answer to OP's question. That can be found in the comments and in @thisisayush's post. But here
is a one-liner, demonstrating that it can be done without redefining a string variable in a loop. As strings are immutable they are not the first choice when it comes to accumulating values step by step. Arrays are more versatile and often faster.

```js
                       
const count=(n1,n2)=>Array(n2+1).fill(0).map((_,i)=>i).slice(n1).join(",");
                                

console.log(count(0,8));
console.log(count(2,5));
console.log(count(5,2));
```

The `.fill(0)` looks a bit superfluous here, but it is necessary, since `.map()` will not iterate over `undefined` elements.

Answer (score -1):

You can greatly simplify the code by incrementing the number in a loop and pushing the resulting number into an array. Once all of the numbers are in the array, you can use the `Array.prototype.toString` method to convert the array into a comma-separated string:

**Source**

```
const count = (start, end) => {
  if (start > end) return "";
  let out = [];
  let idx = start - 1;
  while (++idx <= end) out.push(idx);
  return out.toString();
};

exports.count = count;
```

**Tests**

```
const { strict: assert } = require('node:assert');
const { count } = require('./index');

assert.equal(count(0, 10), "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10");
assert.equal(count(2, 5), "2,3,4,5");
assert.equal(count(5, 2), "");
```